# ¿Como traer una branch que no tengo en mi proyecto actual?

Tags: git

Tengo una duda como puedo traer una branch que no tengo en mi proyecto actual, tengo un proyecto que hice un clone a una branch especifica llamada "newTemplate" ahora en el repositorio hay una branch llamada "master", lo que quiero hacer es hacer un clone a una branch especifica y se agregue a mi proyecto, pero con git clone no lo puedo hacer porque traeria el proyecto en una carpeta diferente.

Explicacion:

//Proyecto Actual

```
Git status
=> newTemplate
```

Lo que yo quiero:
Hacer un pull o clone que me traiga todo lo que tenga la branch master en el repositorio de tal manera que al final quede de la siguiente manera.

//Proyecto deseado

```
Git status
=>master (La branch traida desde el repositorio)
=>newTemplate
```

Estuve tratando con git clone -b branch url-remote pero me trae todo en una carpeta diferent y basicamente tengo 2 proyectos

Comment: Creo que lo que quieres hacer es un `git fetch`. Eso debería traer la información de las ramas del repositorio remoto sin tocar tus ramas locales.

Comment: Quiero es traer una rama del repositorio remoto que no existe en mi proyecto local

Comment: una vez que hagas el fetch la rama sería visible... solo tendrías que hacer un `git checkout master` para que se cree la rama local

Comment: Es el mismo proyecto y tiene como origen el proyecto remoto. Al hacer fetch, traes la rama y queda disponible al clón local. Ya después verás si incluyes los cambios _en tu rama local_ (pero eso es otra cosa)

Answer (score 1):

Podes probar esto:

```
git fetch origin <nombre-branch>
```

seguido

```
git checkout <nombre-branch>
```

Para ver todas las ramas que tenes en tu repo local, podes hacer esto:

```
git branch -a
```

Answer (score 0):

Posicionate en el master haciendo:

```
git checkout master
```

luego realizas un merge:

```
git merge newTemplate
```

entonces esos cambios que no ves en el master se agregan.
depende la herramienta que uses tiene que darte como resultado: fast-forward.